# Proving number of instances is finite

Tags: agda

Suppose, I wanted to postulate a write-consistency rule:

```
postulate
  writeconsistent : {A B : Set} {var : A} {wval rval : B} ->
    (w : W var wval) (r : R var rval) -> (store w) hb (load r) ->
    (p : (wval' : B) -> (w' : W var wval') ->
                    Either ((store w') hb (store w)) ((load r) hb (store w'))) ->
    wval == rval
```

This is to say that given a write `w` and a read `r` if you can prove that any other write `w'` either happens-before `w`, or happens-after `r`, then we have proof that `r` reads the value written by `w`.

But to furnish the function that can order exactly all writes `w'` seems problematic. It seems it would always be possible to only write a function that can prove something about specific subset of all possible writes.

How to restrict the type of proof `p` in such a way that it only requires some known writes to be ordered like that?